# How do I fix "failed to set new screen configuration" when moving to fullscreen in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I used SFML to create a small C++ game for a class in a windows environment, using Visual Studio 2015. As a personal project, I tried to port the game over to a Linux environment, seeing as how SFML is advertised as multi-platform. However, upon doing so, I was met with some problems. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and nothing seems to be working correctly!

I tried making a test window that's 640x480, and then tried to make it fullscreen. The screen appears to be making the transition to fullscreen, but when I look at the terminal, every time I switch to fullscreen, it prints "failed to set new screen configuration". I checked the valid fullscreen resolutions on my monitor and 640x480 was one of them.

I'm about ready to give up on SFML and moving to SDL. Everything worked like a charm on a Windows environment, but migrating to Ubuntu has just been nothing but trouble. How do I fix my fullscreen?

---

Here is my fullscreen code:

```
if(keyReleased)
{
    keyReleased = false;

    if(style == FULLSCREEN)
    {
        this->create(sf::VideoMode(640,480,32), "WINDOW", sf::Style::Default);
        style = WINDOWED;
    }
    else
    {
        this->create(sf::VideoMode(640,480,32), "WINDOW", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
        style = FULLSCREEN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Game Dev! You will note I have removed commentary irrelevant to the question. I do see one further problem; this is not the sort of site where you list *all* your problems, and expect us to solve them. I also observe that you said they were *examples* - it is important to remember that, as examples, they are the only ones we can even begin to help with - as they are the only problems you have actually told us about.

Comment: That said, listing potentially unrelated problems in the one question often makes it too broad. Instead of voting to close this question, I am going to remove one of the problems from the equation (sound, simply because it is the second provided problem). Simply post a second question asking about full screen, and remember to post additional questions for additional problems / questions. Cheers